# Anexar arquivo usando WebBrowser Delphi

Tags: delphi, email, envio-de-email, delphi-xe3

eu estou desenvolvendo uma ferramente para automatizar o envio de e-mails da empresa, queria saber como faço para carregar automáticamente um anexo como nessa screenshot

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Vale lembrar que preciso fazer uso do TWebBrowser .

Preciso que ele faça isso, ao clicar no botão, automáticamente ele adicione o anexo !
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é possível fazer isso que você quer, pois essa propriedade é *somente leitura*, como você pode [ver aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Getting_information_about_selected_file(s)), veja o item **name**, isso é devido a questões de segurança.

Comment: O que você pode fazer é enviar o(s) arquivo(s) separadamente usando o `IdHTTP`.

Comment: zekk, pode me da um exemplo de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível alterar esse campo pois ele é *somente leitura* devido a [questões de segurança](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535128(v=vs.85).aspx).

O que você pode fazer é enviar o arquivo separadamente usando os componentes do [Indy](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Indy), o `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` e `TIdHTTP`.

```
Uses
  IdMultipartFormData, IdHTTP,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient;

//....

procedure EnviarArquivo(const URL, Campo, Arquivo: string);
var
  IdHttp: TIdHTTP;
  Parametros: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  SS: TStringStream;
begin
  IdHttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  SS := TStringStream.Create();
  try
    Parametros := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      Parametros.AddFile(Campo, Arquivo);
      try
        IdHttp.Post(URL, Parametros, SS);
        ShowMessage('Status: ' + IntToStr(IdHttp.ResponseCode));
      except
        on E: Exception do
          ShowMessage('Post Error: ' + E.Message);
      end;
    Memo1.Text := SS.DataString;
    finally
      Parametros.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHttp.Free;
    SS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Use assim:

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EnviarArquivo('<URL>', 'attachmentElement', '<CaminhoDoArquivo>');
end;
```

Comment: Só uma duvida.. a URL eu passo apenas a principal, ou preciso analisar os GET/POST para ter a URL exata.. ?

Comment: Se não me engano, você precisa passar os dados como `Parametros` no `IdHttp.Post`

Comment: @Ronald Funcionou?